# How do I update the transactions uploaded to Yodlee's DAG?

Tags: yodlee

We are trying to verify that our download logic is able to save new transactions when they are added to the bank account. We are uploading a custom XML file to the DAG and the first download after linking the account works fine. After we edit the XML file locally to add a new transaction and upload the file again to the same account, we still get the old data when we request the bank transactions again.

Is it possible to test this scenario using the DAG?

**Updated question**

We call `startSiteRefresh` before we call `executeUserSearchRequest`.

We get

```
{"siteRefreshStatus":{"siteRefreshStatusId":1,"siteRefreshStatus":"REFRESH_TRIGGERED"},"siteRefreshMode":{"refreshModeId":2,"refreshMode":"NORMAL"},"updateInitTime":1401995207,"nextUpdate":1401996107,"code":0,"suggestedFlow":{"suggestedFlowId":2,"suggestedFlow":"REFRESH"},"itemRefreshInfo":[{"memItemId":19416156,"itemSuggestedFlow":{"suggestedFlowId":2,"suggestedFlow":"REFRESH"},"errorCode":0,"retryCount":0}],"noOfRetry":0}
```

and then `executeUserSearchRequest` returns the same data.

Comment: Are you editing the DAG XML file correctly? There might be a reason you are not able to see the updated transactions as you have edited the DAG XML correctly(just double check that please). Or if you have missed any value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you editing the DAG XML file correctly? There might be a reason you are not able to see the updated transactions as you have edited the DAG XML correctly(just double check that please). Or if you have missed any value. And after uploading it to DAG site are you refreshing the account? If No then please refresh the account after uploading edited DAG XML and try to check if you are getting new transactions or not.

## **Edit 1: Based on your comment(which explains the problem).**

To explain you there are two steps to retrieve the data from Yodlee(this is just for your understanding actual number of steps would be more).

**Step 1:** When you add you account(in this case it is DAG site) or Refresh the already added account(Refresh means to pull the latest data from Bank site for an already added account). Then in this step Yodlee gets the data from the respective Bank web site(here DAG site).

**Step 2:** Retrieve the data from Yodlee- As Yodlee has retrieved the data from Bank web site now you need to retrieve the data from Yodlee.

As per your comment, we see you are updating DAG XML and uploading i.e. A new transactions is available at Bank website but Yodlee doesn't know about it. So, if you call API to retrieve data from Yodlee you'll get old transactions. Our suggestion is to use Refresh APIs present over [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference) to update Yodlee DataBase with the latest transactions. After that when you'll call APIs to retrieve data from Yodlee you'll get latest transactions as well.

**Summary:**
Refresh your account(Dag Site) instead of adding it again and then retrieve the transactions. You'll get the latest transactions.

Comment: We get the new transactions if we link the bank account again but not if we query the transactions of the existing link.

Comment: @BrunoSilva - I have edited my answer to explain you the process and what you need to change in your implementation.

Comment: Do I have to wait 24 hours after I add a transaction to a DAG site? The docs say "Because of this, the Aggregation Engine will not be able to get new transactions more than once a day. Forcing the system to refresh will not bring in additional data if the account was refreshed less than 24 hours". Does this also apply here?

Comment: No, you need not to wait for 24 hrs. Could you please modify all the transactions details and then try to add new transaction in DAG XML? For e.g please modify the uniqueId present in transactions node and other details like transDate, Desc & Amount and then try. It should work.